# 'mail my_name' command cannot send message

Tags: virtualbox, mail

Results of running the command `mail my_name` :

```
$ mail my_name   
Cc: 
Subject: me
this mail
ctr d
cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
$
```

I am new to Unix, just started learning, reading [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix_Programming_Environment). I am using Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox. I tried to send a mail to myself from the terminal by following these instructions on page 8 of the book in the link:

> The proper way to log out is to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> instead of a command; this tells the shell
>   that there is no more input...
>
> ...Sending mail to someone is straightforward. Suppose it is to go to the
>   person with the login name `nico`. The easiest way is this:
>
> ```
> $ mail mico     
> Now type in the letter on   
> as many lines as you like...
> ```
>
> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
>   signals the end of the letter by telling mail that there is no more
>   input.

I don't know if I configured my mail right (I am trying to reconfigure my mail again, but don't know how to go about it). When I configured my mail, I didn't give an email address, which I found odd.

Comment: The question is put on hold by @Byte Commander and Thomas Ward. Let me try and clarify. In the book, am reading, I was asked, as practice, to send a mail to myself. I typed mail mynameeee. mynameeee is my name on the system, when I type who command. Next Cc: was prompted, I pressed enter. Next Subject: was prompted I entered "me", then pressed enter. then I typed "this Mail", then pressed enter. Next I pressed ctr d, which is supposed to send the mail right?

Comment: Did the word "postfix" appear anywhere in the terminal when you did this? Or if it didn't appear, at least tell me the page of the book that you are reading where the instructions you followed are because I just downloaded it

Comment: @karel. The book is The Unix Programming Environment by Kernighan & Pike. Page 9. Sorry am giving this part of your answer just now. From my mobile, I didn't see the full question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58318/discussion-between-evan-and-karel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mail needs to be configured in order to receive messages from local users. The easiest way to configure mail is to install sendmail with `sudo apt sendmail` and the sendmail program will work for 3 to 5 minutes when it is being installed and it will configure mail automatically. `sendmail` requires additional configuration to send mail via the internet, which I will skip here because your question is about how to use the `mail` program to send a message to a local user.

Then type `mail` to start the program and after the `?` prompt type the number of a message to read it in the terminal. It can take a few minutes to get a notification that you have received a new message after it is sent. Then you will see that the new message has been added to the list of messages in your inbox.

If you get the error message: `cannot send message: Process exited with non-zero status` that means that mail did not exit correctly. The way to avoid getting this error message is to make the next line after the end of the body of the message a newline containing only the **.** character and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This indicates the end of the message. Then press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit composing the message. Alternatively you can do what it says on page 8 of *The Unix Programming Environment* and press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to signal the end of the message by telling the command-line shell that there is no more input.

Comment: Sorted. To avoid the error message, when you send the mail, I typed "." at the end of the body of the message( didn't press enter to go to newline,  before typing ".", although that works too, but when you read the mail, the "." appears alone on it's separate line)to signify end of the mail, then pressed enter to go to newline, after which I pressed ctrl-d. Also you can type ctrl-d at the end of the body of the message, press enter, then type control-d, like in the book. Unable to find this on the man page, don't know if because still don't know my way around the man page. Cheers mate

Comment: Ctrl+D is not in the man page for `mail` because it's for the whole command-line shell, not just for `mail`. I found it in [UNIX Control-Key Commands](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~rootd/catdoc/guide/TheGuide_38.html). It's also probably hiding in the Ubuntu man pages somewhere. I bet user Radu Rădeanu who is my #1 source for shell scripting information at Ask Ubuntu knows where to find the UNIX Control-Key Commands in Ubuntu.

Comment: I mean like while reading the mail, you get prompted with ? What you are supposed to do. Bear with me if the question is a dumb question :)

Comment: ? is the command prompt in `mail`. If you type anything after the ? command prompt, it can interrupt the normal reading of a message and show something else instead. If you have only 10 messages and type a larger number than 10, it will show an error message and let you keep reading the current message.